# After Homebutton click then on Share: Intent.getExtras empty

Tags: android, android-intent, onresume

As described in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) I added my app to the share list. This works great as long as the share activity isn't started. But if the share activity is currently opened and the user clicks on the Home Button, then opens the gallery, then shares a picture the getExtras() Bundle of the Intent is null. Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And the method I call in OnResume of my Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
            Object o = extras.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            if (o != null) {
                Uri imageUri = (Uri) o;
            }
}
```

Does somebody have a similiar problem, or why is the Bundle null if the activity is only Restarted and Resumed?

Comment: is this the main Launcher activity ?

Comment: No, it's an activity launched from the MainActivity.

Comment: you need to pass that bundle to that activity to. Like Intent i .... i.setArguments();

Comment: So when I start the activity in the MainActivity I should pass the MainActivity bundle to the ShareActivity whilest creating it?

Comment: Exactly! you have to pass data from one to another.

Comment: Sorry but that didn't work, I think you misunderstood me, what my problem is when I'm in the ShareActivity, then click the HomeButton, open gallery, share a picture, the getExtras Bundle is null because onCreate isn't called and thus I need to somehow get the Uri of Image shared without Oncreate being called.

Comment: paste your complete code. and manifest too

Comment: Okay i now see my problem, I'll post a solution, thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've set `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the manifest file for my activity and I've set the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` for starting the intent. This was the reason the Activity didn't get recreated. I removed both and it now works.